# How to set SelectList Values From DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, selectlist

I have city names and licence plates. Licence plates starts from 1 to 100.

I want to show cities from licence plates like 32,54,88, 1,2,3,4,5...100

Licence plate 32,54,88 cities are most choosen cities in my country so i want to show them first.

My database schema is like that:

- LicencePlateId= 32 , CityName = "City1"
- LicencePlateId= 54, CityName= "City2"
- LicencePlateId=88, CityName="City3"
- LicencePlateId= 1, CityName="...."
- LicencePlateId= 2, CityName="...."
- LicencePlateId= 3, CityName="...."
- LicencePlateId= 4, CityName="...."

I get all cities from db with this code. I have no problem

```
List<CityVM> myCity= new List<CityVM>();
  myCity= CityBL.GetAllCities();
```

Than i add cities to a SelectList

```
 List<SelectListItem> cityList= new List<SelectListItem>();
    {
        for (var i = 1; i < myCity.Count + 1; i++)
        {
        cityList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = myCity.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Id == i).Ad.ToString(), Value = i.ToString() });
        }

        cityList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "All Cities ", Value = "100" });
    }
```

but when i look at the View part dropdown is coming like that:

- LicencePlate= 1, CityName="....."
- LicencePlate= 2, CityName="....."
- LicencePlate= 3, CityName="....."

How can i start from LicencePlateId= 32 ?

Comment: What property in your database/data model indicates how often they are used?

Comment: CityId = license plate i mean. I'll change the code. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to sort by _most used 3 cities first_ there has to be a property which indicates how often they are used

Comment: You're right. I couldnt tell what i want so i edit my summary again.

Comment: If the data is coming out of the database in the order you have written it, you could just do `foreach(var city in myCity){...}` instead of a `for` loop. It would definitely be safer if you have some sort of sorting you can apply tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add items to `List<SelectListItem>` in the order they located in `List<CityVM>` either using `for` or `foreach` :

```
for (int i = 0; i < myCity.Count - 1; i++)
{
    cityList.Add(new SelectListItem 
                 { 
                    Text = myCity[i].Ad.ToString(), 
                    Value = myCity[i].Id.ToString() 
                 });
}

cityList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "All Cities ", Value = "100" });
```

Comment: thank you very much. i didn't see Value = myCity[i].Id.ToString() part.